# What do you think is this?

Tags: riddle, word

check this out!

> What is it that all men have one of it's longer on some men  than on
>   others, the pope doesn't use his and a man gives it to his wife  after
>   they're married?

Answer please, .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> His surname!
>  
>  (You could also go with an inappropriate male appendage, as a joke)

**Reasoning for the former**

> 'All' men have surnames, clearly some are longer than others. The pope is addressed as 'Pope (first name)' and generally a wife changes her surname after marriage.